# Can anyone identify the font in this image?

Tags: fonts, font-identification

could anyone identify the font in the image below? I've found a lot of fonts that are very similar, but none that are dead on matches.

[image: Wolves logo]

Comment: For future reference, try using [WhatTheFont](http://www.whatthefont.com/ "What the Font"), which allows you to upload an image and then it will help you pick which fonts it likely is a match for.

Comment: @AdamD: While that's excellent advice in general, it's unlikely to help the OP is this case. (I just tried it, and got no results even remotely like the font in the picture.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think I may have found it. I think it may be [CollegiateFLF](http://www.dafont.com/collegiateflf.font).